# can someone please explain the last two params of arcTo?

Tags: android, path

I'm trying to draw a rectangle with rounded corners. I have a javascript path that does this, but the javascript arcTo method takes a rectangle (to define its oval) and then one param which sets the sweep.

However, in the Android version there are three params. the rectangle oval (which I think I have defined correctly) and then the startAngle and sweepAngle (which I'm not understanding the usage of), but my arcs don't look anything like what I'm expecting when I noodle with how I'm guessing they should work.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial on this?

Specifically I'm trying to understand what would the two params look like if I was trying to draw an arc (on a clock face) from 12 - 3, and then assuming I had a line that ran down from the 3 and then needed to round the corner from 3 to 6 and so forth.

Here's my code (disregard the arc numbers in there now... that's just the latest iteration of my guessing at how this may work, having failed on the previous, more sensible attempts):

```
Path ctx = new Path();
        ctx.moveTo(X+5,Y); //A
        ctx.lineTo(X+W-5,Y);//B
        ctx.arcTo(new RectF(X+W, Y, X+W, Y+5), -180, 90); //B arc

        ctx.lineTo(X+W,Y+H-5); //C
        ctx.arcTo(new RectF(X+W,Y+H,X+W-5,Y+H),90,180); //C arc

        ctx.lineTo(X+W/2 +6,Y+H);
        ctx.lineTo(X+W/2,Y+H+8);
        ctx.lineTo(X+W/2-6,Y+H);
        ctx.lineTo(X+5,Y+H);
        ctx.arcTo(new RectF(X,Y+H,X,Y+H-5),180,270);

        ctx.lineTo(X,Y+5);
        ctx.arcTo(new RectF(X,Y,X+5,Y),270,0);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(0xffff00ff);

        canvas.drawPath(ctx, p);
```

much obliged.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

odd that no one piped in with an answer, once I found it (it wasn't easy to find) it was really straight forward.

So, the way it works is this:
Assuming you want to draw a rounded corner at 12 - 3 (using clock reference):
you start your path and when you need the line to arc you define a rectangle whose upper left corner is the place where your line is currently terminated and whose lower right corner is the place that you want the arc to go to, so if you imagine a square whose X,Y is 12 (on the clock)  and whose X+W,Y+H is 3 that's the square you need.

Now, imagine that you have an oval in that square (in this example it's a circular oval, if you want your curve to be more oval-ish, then define your square as a rectangle), you can take any slice of that circle using the last two params of the method.  The first param defines the angle where you want to start cutting.  If we're using a compass, 0 degrees is East (not sure why, I'm not a geometry expert... is this normal? I always think of 0 being North, but all the programming geometry examples I see have 0 as East, maybe someone will comment on why that is).

The second param defines how much of the circle you want. If you want the whole circle you put 360 if you want half the circle you put 180 etc.

So, in our case since we want to round the corner from 12 to 3, we put 270 as our starting degree and grab 90 degrees of the circle.

Lastly, when you're done with this process, the line now thinks of itself as being at 3pm so you can continue lineTo(ing) from there.
So... here's my fixed code for my shape (it has a little triangle in it, but that's neither here nor there, the actual rounded parts are B-C, D-E, I-J, and K-A. All the rest are straight lines.

```
int arc = 25;
    public Cursor(int X, int Y, int W, int H){
        /*
         *   A            B
         * K                C 
         * J                D
         *   I   H   F    E
                   G
         */
        int Ax = X+ arc;
        int Ay = Y;
        int Bx = X + W - arc;
        int By = Y;
        int Cx = X + W;
        int Cy = Y + arc;
        int Dx = Cx;
        int Dy = (Y + arc) + (H - arc*2);
        int Ex = Bx;
        int Ey = Y + H;
        int Fx = X+W/2 +6;
        int Fy = Ey;
        int Gx = X+W/2;
        int Gy = Y+H+8;
        int Hx = X+W/2-6;
        int Hy = Ey;
        int Ix = Ax;
        int Iy = Hy;
        int Jx = X;
        int Jy = Dy;
        int Kx = X;
        int Ky = Cy;


        Path ctx = new Path();
        ctx.moveTo(Ax,Ay); //A
        ctx.lineTo(Bx,By);//B
        ctx.arcTo(new RectF(Bx, By, Cx, Cy), 270, 90); //B-C arc

        ctx.lineTo(Dx,Dy); //D
        ctx.arcTo(new RectF(Dx - arc, Dy, Ex + arc, Ey),0,90); //D-E arc

        ctx.lineTo(Fx, Fy); //E-F
        ctx.lineTo(Gx, Gy); //F-G
        ctx.lineTo(Hx, Hy); //G-H
        ctx.lineTo(Ix, Iy); //H - I
        ctx.arcTo(new RectF(Jx, Jy, Ix, Iy),90,90);// I = J arc

        ctx.lineTo(Kx, Ky); //K
        ctx.arcTo(new RectF(Ax - arc, Ay, Kx + arc, Ky),180,90); //K - A arc
        ctx.lineTo(Ax, Ay); //K



        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setColor(0xffffffff);
        p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawPath(ctx, p);    
        p.setColor(0xff000000);
        p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(3);            
        canvas.drawPath(ctx, p);



    }
```

Comment: Hey, I'm having problem while drawing arcs in a path, i tried to follow your recommendations but I couldn't get it.. could you see the question I asked? There I have my problem detailed so it is better for you to understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449339/how-to-define-te-startangle-and-sweepangle-for-arcto-method-android Thanks ! :)

Comment: imagine your arc to be enclosed by a rectangle (and extending all the way around the inside of that rectangle, even though only the part you want shown will be shown).  The first parameter is the degree inside your oval where the point will start, and the second is the number of degrees you want to grab of the full oval to be the segment that is your arc.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was passing the final degree value to sweepAngle parameter. I had to pass how many degrees I want do grab considering the startAngle parameter, and not the finalAngle

Comment: just as I said! :) I think my answer deserves another up-vote!

Comment: the docs give the RectF oval as "The bounds of oval defining shape and size of the arc", implying the rectangle to cover the entire oval the arc would be a part of, not just one enclosing the arc as in your example text. that's how I've been using it, although it's often hard determining the start and sweep angles outside of simple 90 degree arcs.

Comment: @michael, not sure if you're saying that my explanation is wrong, but I am 100% sure it's correct because it works exactly as detailed. You're welcome to cut and paste the code. It will work without any modification. Just put it on a Canvas.

Comment: East as 0 degree reference is standard maths, also counting counter-clockwise.

Comment: This helped but also mislead in a very important way. The approach doesn't apply to the general case and is imprecise.  Drawing an arc from 12 - 3, given their coordinates, is done by defining a rectangle that circumscribes the clock (not with upper-left at 12/lower-right at 3) and specifying a starting angle of 270 and sweep angle of 90. The code doesn't draw arc from B to C, e.g., rather a straight line from B that is half the length of the rect, then an arc, then a straight line half the length of rect to C.  If B and C are not at 90 angle, it fails. This got me started though, so thanks!

Comment: @Jayz7522, I'm not sure what you mean, and I'd love to correct my sample if there's anything I said that's not right, but I suspect you're misunderstanding something.  Can you elaborate on what you feel I've misrepresented.

Comment: @GeniaS., Sure, but perhaps reread my above, which is fairly precise.  The quickest way to illustrate what I describe is to edit your code like so: choose a corner, say upper right, and draw the rect in some noticeable color.  Instead of starting your arc at 270 (on the rect), start it at 300, e.g.  You'll notice that the arc does not begin at the upper left hand corner of the rect, but at 300th deg. of a circle inscribed in your rect. Your answer implies that if drawing an arc from point A to B, one should choose a rect with upper left corner A, lower right B, which is not the case.

Comment: @Jayz7522 - interesting, now that I'm really considering what you're saying you're obviously entirely right and my explanation is totally wrong. How the heck is it that it works?? I wish I had the time to sort through it all again.

Comment: Great explaining @GeniaS. Using the analog clock to explain angles makes everything a piece of cake.. I just created a pizza slice with less than 4 lines of code for my path object. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: "0 degrees is East (not sure why..." - think of it as a tangent, the tangent at the easterly edge would be a vertical line, hence 0 degrees

Answer (score 8):

This answer visually explains all [`arcTo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path#arcTo(android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean)) parameters using four examples.

`arcTo` takes the following parameters:

```java
public void arcTo(RectF oval, 
                  float startAngle, 
                  float sweepAngle, 
                  boolean forceMoveTo)
```

where `RectF`'s constructor takes:

```java
RectF(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
```

[image: ArchTo parameters explained visually]

(Hopefully this visualization is less painful and less mystifying than reading the official `arcTo` documentation.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this example, it makes the parameters very clear to understand. 
From what I read in the dev docs of Android you can probably spare yourself some of the "lineTo()" calls (except those to points F,G,H), since arcTo automatically adds a lineTo when the first point of the arc is not the last point drawn...

As for why 0 starts East, it is so because of math and trigonometry lessons generally assume that the 0 degrees mark is the point where the trigonometric circle (circle with center 0,0 and radius 1) intersects with the X-axis, which is East (these same lessons however generally count the angles counter-clockwise, so 90 degrees becomes north and 270 is south, whereas on Android it seems the angles are counted clockwise)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code (pieced together from one of my classes) to draw a filled, rounded corner rectangle and then adding a stroked rectangle to give it a border:

```
//Initializing some stuff
_paint = new Paint();
_rect = new RectF();
_radius = 10;
_bgColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;
_borderColor = 0xFFCCCCCC;

//Doing dimension calculations
_rect.left = 0;
_rect.top = 0;
_rect.right = this.getWidth() - 1;
_rect.bottom = this.getHeight() - 1;

//painting
//draw the background
_paint.setColor(_bgColor);
_paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
canvas.drawRoundRect(_rect, _radius, _radius, _paint);

//draw the border
_paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
_paint.setColor(_borderColor);
_paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
canvas.drawRoundRect(_rect, _radius, _radius, _paint);
```

Comment: I appreciate this, but this is not what I'm after... I want to understand the arcTo method. My shape isn't strictly speaking a rectangle, it has a little arrow at the bottom.